# How do I split an entry in the factor type column using a separator in R?

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataset which looks like this after using the melt function (from the reshape2 package):

```
 CO2AndProd <- melt(CO2AndProd, id.vars = "y")
 head(CO2AndProd)
```

Result:

```
         y          variable              value
1 2015 gas-CCG;co2noramp 32578115.707861189
2 2016 gas-CCG;co2ramp 28516257.629492953
3 2017 hydro;co2noramp  28345649.67523421
4 2018 hydro;co2ramp 29054823.023870178
```

I want to split the variable column into two columns like this:

```
      variable1        variable2
 gas-CCG               co2noramp 
 gas-CCG               co2ramp 
 hydro                 co2noramp  
 hydro                 co2ramp
```

So I tried to convert the column to character in order to use strsplit, but because melt() makes the variable column into a factor datatype, this is what happens:

```
 CO2AndProd[2] <- as.character(CO2AndProd[2])
```

[Result(see snapshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeM6N.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeM6N.png)

Can anybody help?

Comment: did not see you wanted to use strsplit, I updated the answer to this effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `separate` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, variable, c('variable1','variable2'), sep=';', remove=F)
#     y          variable variable1 variable2    value
#1 2015 gas-CCG;co2noramp   gas-CCG co2noramp 32578116
#2 2016   gas-CCG;co2ramp   gas-CCG   co2ramp 28516258
#3 2017   hydro;co2noramp     hydro co2noramp 28345650
#4 2018     hydro;co2ramp     hydro   co2ramp 29054823
```

Or base `R` with `gsub`:

```
pattern = "(.*);(.*)"
transform(df, variable1 = gsub(pattern, "\\1", df$variable),
              variable2 = gsub(pattern, "\\2", df$variable))
```

Or base `R` with `strsplit`:

```
cbind(df, do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$variable), ';')))
```